# Ожидание ответа от пользователя Pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Реализую user бота на Python с помощью Pyrogram, работаю впервые. Нужно сделать ожидание ответа от пользователя. В документации чего то нужного не нашёл, как то костылять через глобальные переменные не вариант. Подскажите, может знает кто?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.message_handler(filters.user(['Username1', 'Username2', 123123]))
def handler(client, message):
    ... # Do something
```

Подробнее: [Filters.user](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/filters#pyrogram.filters.user)